# how to use i18nSupport in java with play framework 2.5.x

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

I recently upgraded my project from 2.3.x to 2.5.x. I have a html page like below. However i can't get the multiple langauge support to work(it used to work with 2.3.x).

```
@()(implicit lang: play.api.i18n.Lang,messages:play.api.i18n.Messages)
```

The controller is written in Java. I have read the migration documentation that i will need to use i18nSupport and import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._ for the language to work.

```
public class EmailController extends Controller {
private myservice.MyEnvironment env;

@Inject
public UserFormHandler(myservice.MyEnvironment) {
    this.env = env;
}
```

But i didn't find any documentation on how to use i18nsupport and import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._ with Java.

1.Can anyone advise how to do that?
2.Can anyone provide an example project on how the internationalization works in 2.5.x?

Answer (score -1):

In play 2.4 Messages class was deprecated, MessagesApi should be injected instead.

More info can about migrating to Play 2.4 can be found in the official site:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration24#dependency-injected-components